# Retrieve symfony parameters of RedirectResponse

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-http-foundation

I use the stand alone `HttpFoundation` component of Symfony in my MVC app, and native PHP files for the view templates (not Twig).

The functions in the controller can successfully execute a URL redirection to the template path as follows:

```
return new RedirectResponse('path_to_php_file');
```

If I pass also parameters with this syntax, how to retrieve them on the PHP file?

```
return new RedirectResponse('path_to_php_file', 302,  array('params' => 'sometext'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning the RedirectResponse object to another method of yours, there are getters on the object for the URL `getTargetUrl()` & `getStatusCode()` available on or through the RedirectResponse object, and the `$headers` is a public property that can be read directly (that comes from the inner Response class).

Comment: This is a URL redirection to a PHP file (HTML form), not to a method.

Comment: check what you'll get from the server variables - `dump($request->server);` from the receiving page.